# dapper multli innerjoin and left join mapping

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Coin>();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Coin,  CoinCategoryCategory, CoinCategory,CoinAnnouncement, Coin>(
                @"SELECT c.*, coinCat.*, cat.*, a.*
                    FROM Coins c
                    INNER JOIN CoinCategoriesCategories coinCat ON coinCat.CoinId = c.CoinId
                    INNER JOIN CoinCategories cat ON cat.CategoryId = coinCat.CategoryID
                    LEFT JOIN CoinAnnouncements a ON a.CoinId = c.CoinId", 
                (c, cat, coinCat, a) =>
                {

                    Coin coin;
                    if (!lookup.TryGetValue(c.CoinId, out coin))
                    {
                        lookup.Add(c.CoinId, coin = c);
                    }

                    if (coin.Categories == null)
                    {
                        coin.Categories = new List<CoinCategory>();

                    }
                    if (coin.Announcements == null)
                    {
                        coin.Announcements = new List<CoinAnnouncement>();

                    }
                    if (a.Id >0)
                    {
                        coin.Announcements.Add(new CoinAnnouncement { Id = a.Id, CreatedDateUtc = a.CreatedDateUtc, Summary = a.Summary });
                    }
                    coin.Categories.Add(new CoinCategory { CategoryId = coinCat.CategoryId, Description = coinCat.Description });
                    return coin;
                }, splitOn: "CategoryId, CoinId");

            return lookup.Values;
        }
    }
```

even though there is an announcement for a coin, `a` fields are always blanks/default values

Here are the query results in SQL Query (direct against DB)

[image]

Of course, if I change the `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` then only one record is returned and everything works as expected

Should I be splitting this query into multiple queries?

Comment: For CoinId 17 you actualy have results for CoinAnnouncements colummns....are you sure you have data in CoinAnnouncements table for coins with id 15 and 16?

Comment: This is more a SQL question then a Dapper / C# question, also.